# 64bit dividend on 32bit architecture, works in assembly but not in C

Tags: c, gcc, x86, integer-division

I have a 64bit dividend and a 32bit divisor.

GCC do not seem to be able to create this kind of assembly. It complains about `undefined reference to '__udivdi3'`, I know this is because I use the `-nostdlib` flag. I can however not use any stdlibs.

The 64bit variables are of type `unsigned long long`.

Are there any more elegant way to do this other than this inline assembly?
My goals is: `my64bit / 32bitDivisor`.

```
volatile uint32_t high = my64bit >> 32;
volatile uint32_t low = my64bit;
volatile uint32_t out;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl %0, %%edx\n\t"
    "movl %1, %%eax\n\t"
    "div %2\n\t"
    "movl %%eax, (%3)\n\t"
::  "r" (high), "r" (low), "r" (32bitDivisor) "r" (&out)
:   "%eax", "%edx"
);
```

Comment: copy that function from glibc source code?

Comment: are you sure you cannot link against the libgcc?

Comment: @user3528438 it is not in glibc but libgcc.

Comment: For OS development (which this appears to be) I recommend using a cross compiler (like i686-elf-gcc) and link with `-ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc` . `__udivdi3` is part of GCC's libgcc not the _C_ library. `libgcc` can be used in standalone code, but using a cross compiler like generic i686-elf will make sure there aren't host OS specific code.

Comment: udivdi3 is for uint64/uint64 (only supported by x86-64, 32 bit mode need to depend on library function), but what you need is uint64/uint32 (available in 32 bit mode). Following this logic, you can try turning on optimization, there's a chance that GCC will skip the integer promotion and let you get away without triggering udivdi3.

Comment: Information on building a GCC cross compiler can be found here: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: It's not clear - are you hoping to do division in C without using inline assembly? If so then it would be useful to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with details of your compiler and switches, and the error message.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but to clean up the inline assembly a bit by making better use of input and output constraints you could do: `__asm__("div %[divisor]" : "=a" (out), "=d" (remainder) : [divisor] "rm" (divisor32), "1" (high), "0" (low) : "cc");` . With optimizations if you don't use `remainder` the compiler should easily be able to eliminate it. I'd also question your use of volatile variables in this code but since I don't know the context I can't say for certain that you won't need them here

Comment: x86 DIV is a 32-bit division, it produces a 32-bit result. The fact that the dividend is 64-bit doesn't make it a 64-bit operation.

Comment: x86 DIV only works if the output fits in 32 bits, which the compiler cannot guess from the fact that you are dividing 64 bits by 32 bits. Inline asm (your version is broken btw) is the only way I know to generate that code.